# What's the easiest way to passively record the load time of every web page I visit?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox, web

I have to access various Atlassian tools (Confluence, Jira, etc) on three different sites. I feel like one is significantly slower than the others. I want to record the actual page load speeds I encounter in my day to day work to verfiy this.

Is there a place where my browser logs the page load speed of every page I visit (for example, with my history)? If not, is there an extension that will passively log this info as I go about my work?

(I have tried Firefox's built in logging, and it is too verbose. Most of the performance testing extensions seem to be focused on actively testing a site or page, not gathering info passively in the background.)

Solution for Mac required, Firefox preferred, Chrome will do.

Comment: perhaps you could use a local proxy, the log files should have what you want.